# I want to set the game so that the player announce who is out and who wins

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

I have this script here and here is what I would like to happen.

I would like the game to announce who is out and who has won the game.

Here is Memory Shift for instance. So this is a turn based game. The annoucner calls out a pattern.

Let's say in this scernario. Player 1 shifts it right, player 2 shifts it wrong, player 1 is out and player 2 wins.

I want the script to announce when the player is out and who wins.

Here is an example script on Memory Shift.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MemoryShift2 : BaseShift
{
    [SerializeField] public int memoryCount = 3;

    public Dictionary<Player, int> playerVsMemCout = new Dictionary<Player, int>();
    public TileColorType[] tileColTypes = new TileColorType[0];
    public int nxtTileIndex = 0;
    public AudioSource stickAudioSource;
    public AudioClip[] gameMusicLoop;
    private int bkSoundIndex = 0;
    private int turnPlayerCount = 0;
    private Tile lastTileOnGameOver;
    public AudioSource audioSource;
    private MusicType[] currentColors;
    public int Gamemode;
    public Canvas GameModeCanvas;

    public override ShiftType shiftType
    {
        get
        {
            return ShiftType.Memory;
        }
    }

    protected override void StartGame()
    {  
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("MemoryShiftUnlockEndless", 0) == 1)
        {
            GameModeCanvas.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("MemoryShiftUnlockNormal", 0) == 1) {
            GameModeCanvas.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            EndlessMode.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
        else {
            GameModeCanvas.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            playmode = 2;
            for (var i = 0; i < getTotalPlayer.Count; i++)
            {
                playerVsMemCout.Add(getTotalPlayer[i], memoryCount);
            }
            StartPlayerTurn();
            GameLogic();
        }
    }

    public void ClickONSelectModeOfGame(int Gamemode) {
        this.Gamemode = Gamemode;
        playmode = 2;
        for (var i = 0; i < getTotalPlayer.Count; i++)
        {
            playerVsMemCout.Add(getTotalPlayer[i], memoryCount);
        }
        StartPlayerTurn();
        GameLogic();
    }


    protected sealed override void OnMoved(Tile tile)
    {

        if (currTileColor == tile.tileColor)
        {
            nxtTileIndex++;

            if (nxtTileIndex >= tileColTypes.Length)
            {
                if (GameManager.shiftersCount != 1 && getTotalPlayer.Count == 1)
                {
                    GameWin();
                    return;
                }

                if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("MemoryShiftUnlockNormal", 0) == 0 && currPlayer.playerScore >= 15)
                {
                    var musics = new List<MusicType>();
                    musics.Add(MusicType.EndlessModeUnlocked);
                    musics.Add(MusicType.ExplainEndlessMode);
                    AudioManger.PlayAudio(musics.ToArray(), onFinished: () => { Debug.Log("Game Win");});    
                    GameWin();
                    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("MemoryShiftUnlockNormal",1);
                    return;
                }

                else if (Gamemode == 1 && currPlayer.playerScore >= 15)
                {
                    GameWin();
                    return;
                }

                if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("MemoryShiftUnlockEndless", 0) == 0 && currPlayer.playerScore >= 20)
                {
                    var musics = new List<MusicType>();
                    musics.Add(MusicType.YouComplete);
                    musics.Add(currentGameModeIntro());
                    AudioManger.PlayAudio(musics.ToArray(), onFinished: () => { Debug.Log("Game Win"); });
                    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("MemoryShiftUnlockEndless", 1);
                    GameWin();
                    return;
                }

                else if (Gamemode == 1 && currPlayer.playerScore >= 15)
                {
                    GameWin();
                    return;
                }

                AudioManger.instance.increasePitch();

                if (playerVsMemCout[currPlayer] <= 9999)
                {
                    //print("Mamory shift 5");
                    playerVsMemCout[currPlayer] += 1;
                }

                currPlayer.playerScore++;
                ScoreChange(currPlayer.playerScore);
                PlayerTurnChange();
            }

            currTileColor = tileColTypes[nxtTileIndex];
            currPlayer.OnHandleMove += OnHandleMove;
        }

        else if (getTotalPlayer.Count > 1)
        {
            //print("Mamory shift 6");
            var nxtTile = getTileForTileType(tileColTypes[nxtTileIndex]);
            HintToMissTile(nxtTile);
            OnPlayerDestroy(currPlayer);
        }

        else if (getTotalPlayer.Count == 1)
        {
            //print("Mamory shift 7");
            var nxtTile = getTileForTileType(tileColTypes[nxtTileIndex]);
            HintToMissTile(nxtTile);
            GameOver();
        }
    }

    MusicType currentGameModeIntro()
    {
        //print("Mamory shift 8");
        if (shiftType == ShiftType.Memory)
        {
            //print("Mamory shift 9");
            return MusicType.MemoryIntro;
        }
        return MusicType.WhoIntro;
    }

    protected override void GameWin()
    {
        //print("Mamory shift 10");
        AudioManger.instance.resetPitch();
        base.GameWin();
    }

    protected virtual void PlayerTurnChange()
    {
        //print("Mamory shift 11");
        if (getTotalPlayer.Count == 1)
        {
            //print("Mamory shift 13");
            bkSoundIndex += 1;
        }

        if (getTotalPlayer.Count > 1)
        {
            //print("Mamory shift 14");
            AudioManger.instance.resetPitch();
            turnPlayerCount += 1;

            if (turnPlayerCount >= getTotalPlayer.Count)
            {
                //print("Mamory shift 15");
                bkSoundIndex += 1;
                turnPlayerCount = 0;
            }
        }

        if (stickAudioSource != null)
        {
            //print("Mamory shift 16");
            stickAudioSource.clip = gameMusicLoop[bkSoundIndex];

            if (bkSoundIndex <= 20)
            {
                //print("Mamory shift 17");
                stickAudioSource.clip = gameMusicLoop[bkSoundIndex];
            }
            else
            {
                //print("Mamory shift 18");
                stickAudioSource.clip = gameMusicLoop[20];
            }
            stickAudioSource.Play();
        }

        nxtTileIndex = 0;
        currPlayer = GetNxtPlayer();
        StartPlayerTurn();
        GameLogic();
    }

    private void HintToMissTile(Tile tile)
    {
        //print("Mamory shift 19");
        //Debug.Log("Hint Tile " + tile.tileColor);

        lastTileOnGameOver = tile;

        var musics = new List<MusicType>();
        musics.Add(MusicHandler.GetMusForTileType(tile.tileColor));
        AudioManger.PlayAudio(MusicHandler.GetPlayerFailShoud(currPlayer.playerType), onFinished: () => { AudioManger.PlayAudio(musics.ToArray(), onFinished: () => { PlayerTurnChange(); }); });
        tile.InVokeIndicate();
    }

    protected override void GameLogic()
    {
        //print("Mamory shift 20");
        var count = playerVsMemCout[currPlayer];
        currentColors = new MusicType[count];
        tileColTypes = new TileColorType[count];

        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var ranType = GetRanTiColType();
            tileColTypes[i] = ranType;
            currentColors[i] = MusicHandler.GetMusForTileType(ranType, true);
        }

        currTileColor = tileColTypes[0];
        PlayLogicMusic(currentColors);
    }

    private void PlayLogicMusic(MusicType[] musics)
    {
        //print("Mamory shift 21");
        var allMusics = new List<MusicType>();
        allMusics.Add(currentPlayAnnounce());
        allMusics.Add(MusicType.Shift);
        allMusics.AddRange(musics);
        //print("Allow to play game :- "+GameManager.CanPlay);

        AudioManger.PlayAudio(allMusics.ToArray(),
            onStartCurrMusic: (type) =>
            {
                OnTileCallFunc(type);
            },
            onFinished: () =>
            {
                //Debug.Log("Tile event done");
                OnTileDone?.Invoke();
                currPlayer.OnHandleMove += OnHandleMove;
                GameManager.CanPlay = true;
            });
    }

    /*protected sealed override void OnPlayerDestroy(Player player)
    {
        playerVsMemCout.Remove(currPlayer);
        base.OnPlayerDestroy(player);
    } */

    protected sealed override void GameOver() //MusicHandler.GetMusForTileType(lastTileOnGameOver.tileColor)
    {
        base.GameOver();
        //print("Mamory shift 24");
        if (GameManager.shiftersCount > 1)
        {
            //print("Mamory shift 25");
            var musics = new List<MusicType>();
            //for (int i = 1; i <= GameManager.shiftersCount; i++)
            //{
                var playerNumber = MusicHandler.GetNumberSound(GameManager.shiftersCount);
                musics.Add(MusicType.SorryPlayer);
                musics.Add(playerNumber);
                musics.Add(MusicType.YourOut);
            //}

            musics.Add(MusicType.RepeatThatRoundAgain);
            AudioManger.PlayAudio(musics.ToArray(), onFinished: () => { GameLogic(); });
        }
        else
        {
            //print("Mamory shift 26");
            var musics = new List<MusicType>();
            musics.Add(MusicType.Play1Fail);
            musics.AddRange(currentColors);
            musics.Add(MusicType.YouHave);
            musics.AddRange(MusicHandler.GetMusForNumber(currPlayer.playerScore));
            musics.Add(MusicType.Shifts);
            musics.Add(MusicType.GameOver);
            AudioManger.PlayAudio(musics.ToArray());
        }
    }

    MusicType currentPlayAnnounce()
    {
        //print("Mamory shift 27");
        var _ind = totalPlayers.IndexOf(currPlayer);
        if (_ind.Equals(0))
            return MusicType.One;
        else if (_ind.Equals(1))
            return MusicType.Two;
        else if (_ind.Equals(2))
            return MusicType.Three;
        else if (_ind.Equals(3))
            return MusicType.Four;
        else if (_ind.Equals(4))
            return MusicType.Five;
        else
            return MusicType.Six;
    }

    void AnounceWinner()
    {
        var _sfxList = new List<MusicType>();
        _sfxList.Add(MusicType.PlayerSound);
        _sfxList.Add(MusicHandler.GetPlayerNumber(currPlayer.playerType));
        _sfxList.Add(MusicType.YouComplete);

        // When all Tile sound played
        AudioManger.PlayAudio(_sfxList.ToArray(), () =>
        {
            GameOver();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not possible to understand what you want. What do you means by "I want the script to announce when the player is out"? Out of what?, what does "announce" mean (call your win function, display someting)? What is it you don't know how to do (display someting with unity, detecting a win)? Try to read your question again from the point a view of  someone that don't know your game. What is a Memory shift for you? Do we need to know that?  Try to explain what your script does so far and why you are stuck

Comment: I would like the musics script to call a function that will announce who won the game. So the voice would say "Player one, you're out. Player two. You win with 2 shfits. This game is over."